# SVNBridge with Xcode giving '200 OK' error

Tags: xcode, svn, xcode4, svnbridge

I'm trying to utilize SVNBridge so that my team can use our existing TFS server as our Xcode repository.

SVNBridge appears to be set up correctly on the TFS server, and I can connect to it from Xcode as an SVN repository to grab everything and commit changes.

However, when I have another member of my team update to grab a file I just committed, they receive the following error:

svn: REPORT of '/!svn/bc/36163/-TFS folder structure-': 200 OK (http://-tfs server url-:8081)

The also happens when they update a file, and I then try to update.

We both have full read/write access to the TFS structure.

There is nothing in the SVNBride logs folder on the TFS server.

Any thoughts on the error, or is there a better solution I should use for this?

Comment: 200 = OK is a standard web server success message... is this really an "error"?

Comment: True, but it is getting thrown as an error in Xcode and the requested action doesn't go through.

Comment: If nobody has an obvious or explicit answer for you, my suggestion would be to set up a test or external (to your company) facing repository and then file a bug with Apple (at http://bugreporter.apple.com) against the Xcode component.  Either Xcode needs to be able to recognize svnbridge responses, or svnbridge needs to be responding in the way (and format) Xcode expects to see.

Answer (score 0):

y0-1, happens all the time for me.

Possible causes are
1) urlscan, check the logs
2) ..svnbridge folders, I usually connect to TFS with native client and delete them, it's a pain cause there are a lot of them usually. After deleting ..svnbridge folders you might want to re-checkout parts of your project where you deleted them and sometimes svnbridge restart is required.

Also svnbridge log usually conatains very usefull info ;)

p.s.
Just realized, that you said that your svnbridge log is clean, that's odd, maybe it is not configured properly(usually folder permissions)

f.e. mine svnbridge log with the similar error on update -

Message  : The item 'blah-blah-blah' does not exist at the specified version.
User     : 
Request  : REPORT /!svn/vcc/default HTTP/1.1